# How to generate completely new migration in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I am new to Laravel and was working on one project, which was 90% completed, and now project is 100% completed.

The project has old Migration files. I have made so many modifications in the tables (added/deleted columns) and/or added new tables in the database, now how do I update/create the Migration for that modifications? Because I don't remember where did I made the changes in the tables.

Do I have to use artisan command to create new migration for users table and all other tables same like this? `php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users` or there is any another way?

I have read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations) but don't get how to do it.

Please correct me if I have made any mistake, because I don't know how to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

We user migration and tinker to Not use phpmyadmin , so if you have altered your tables in any way in phpmyadmin , you are all set , no need to do anything.
If you dont want to use phpmyadmin you can use migration and then start writing the sql code in there ( altering tables , etc)
And as we know the migration php files are located in your  laravelfolder/database/migration . you can edit them there and then run php artisan migration and it will go throw all of them and make the changes in phpmyadmin.
Hope im clear enough :D